# How can I change a list of lat,lon to a shapely polygon object?

Tags: python-3.x, gis, polygon, latitude-longitude, shapely

I have a list of coordinates for a bounding box and a circle on one side of the bounding box. How can I create a polygon object in shapely from these?

I have the coordinates of the bounding box as well as the coordinates of the circle.

The size of the grids inside the shape file must be equal to the grids in the grid world.  How should I change this into a 2D system to train a RL agent.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "please help me" is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question); we don't write code to specification. [You are expected to study the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.

Comment: Shapely documentation contains many examples, check e.g. polygon object (constructor). And possibly read the shapely documentation. It is not long, and it will help you a lot (you know what it can do, and how to quickly find most of answers).